# Determinant properties on scalar multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

My question is about the scalar multiplication changing the result if the matrix is a 2x2.
|3/2 A| + |5/2 A| = 4 |A| ?
and also about:
If B is a 4 by 4 matrix, then det AdjB = 1/det B, when det B is not = to 0. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Given that $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and given a scalar $\alpha$

$\det(\alpha A)=\det((\alpha I)(A))=\det(\alpha I)\det(A)$

Now, notice that $\det(\alpha I)$ is easy to calculate

> $\det(\alpha I)=\alpha^n$

So, $\det(\alpha A)=...$

> $\det(\alpha A)=\alpha^n\det(A)$

Answer (score -1):

$|\frac{3}{2} A| + |\frac{5}{2} A| = (\frac{3}{2})^n|A|+(\frac{5}{2})^n |A|$ may not be equal to 4 |A|

Comment: It is not specified what dimensions $A$ is.  It is possible that they be equal, contrary to what you say.  If we were to assume $|\frac{3}{2}A|+|\frac{5}{2}A|=4|A|$, this tells us one of two things, the value of $n$, or the value of $|A|$.